# How can I mirror a bare repo to a working repo - both on the server?

Tags: git

I really am a git-noob - sorry...

I have a bare repository in `server/app.git`. I have access via ssh.

I want this as supposed as the sharing point for my friends to work on the project.

But I would like to have the master branch somehow mirrored to `server/app` as an working copy to deliver via http.

Is that possible? I guess so.

Comment: If you are using 2.5 or later, I think `git worktree` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you want `server/app` to be a repository (you gonna work there with git) or just a directory checked out from a branch (will be updated regularly from `server/app.git`)?

Comment: @chepner unfortunately 2.13.3 and no update possible

Comment: @phd the latter! It should just be an up to date copy of the master branch, which I can reach via `http://www.domain.tld/server/app` (which is of course not the question here, how to achieve that, it is already on an apache).

Comment: @ChrisPillen 2.13 *is* later than 2.5.

Comment: Oh :D right. It's "thirteen" not "one three" ... been in math mode. Thank you.

Comment: @chepner given what I said to @phd, would you still say, that `worktree` is a suitable solution?

Comment: *Matt Banks* suggests to add `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/mirror/path git checkout -f` to the `hooks/post_receive` (http://mattbanks.me/wordpress-deployments-with-git/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `post-receive` or `post-update` hook on the server side. Example:

In the `server/app.git` repository create a `post-receive` hook: edit `.git/hooks/post-receive` and put the following into it (adapt the path to your directory):

```
git --work-tree=../app checkout -f
```

Make the hook executable:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
```

Now on every push to that repo git will run the hook and the hook will update `../app` directory with the content checked out of the branch.

See http://toroid.org/git-website-howto